# Can I use smart pointer with a mutex member?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

Say I have a dynamic allocated object `foo` which have a `std::mutex` member:

```cpp
#include <mutex>
#include <memory>

class foo {
    public:
        foo()=default;
        ~foo();
    private:
        std::mutex lock;
};

int main(){
    std::unique_ptr<foo> a = std::make_unique<foo>(foo());
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried to use a smart pointer, but it make no sense:

```cpp
rog.cc:4:7: error: use of deleted function 'std::mutex::mutex(const std::mutex&)'
In file included from /opt/wandbox/gcc-head/include/c++/11.0.0/mutex:43,
                 from prog.cc:1:
/opt/wandbox/gcc-head/include/c++/11.0.0/bits/std_mutex.h:94:5: note: declared here
   94 |     mutex(const mutex&) = delete;
      |     ^~~~~
```

shall I must use raw pointer to manage this object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're constructing a temporary object by `foo()` and passing it to `std::make_unique()`. `std::make_unique()` will construct the managed object from the temporary `foo`, but `foo` is not copyable nor moveable.

To get a `std::unique_ptr` managing a default-constructed `foo`, you can just omit the temporary object:

```
std::unique_ptr<foo> a = std::make_unique<foo>();
```